# Should I create a new DB connection for each query ?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my servlet , i have a `.jsp` page that has a form and a `submit button`

Ones a user clicks `submit` a new connection to the teradata database is created and and the result of the query is posted for the user to view it .

I read many questions about servlet to databse connection on Stackoverflow and in [BalusC website](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Is it the right way ? Should I create a new connection to the database every time a user click on the submit button . Or should I use some kind of `DAO` described by BalusC . Or is it good only for authentication ? I am not sure that my currect approach is correct

Comment: Probably not a great idea. You should probably look into using your container's connection pool. If your container does not have one, then you might need to investigate some other connection pool implementations.

Comment: While connection pooling is the Right Way (TM), the cost of opening a completely new connection, even without pooling, compared to the overall request time - this question is really about "connection per request", not "connection per [SQL] query" - should be marginal. I recommend a proper DAL/DAO layer, that utilizes IoC/DI, *independent* of any connection issues or concerns.

Answer (score 4):

You should manage database connection pool google for c3po, creating new connection is costly operation

Answer (score 2):

Use a connection pool. Personally, I like BoneCP. 3CPO is more or less industry standard though.